# Getting a usable variable name from within another variable

Tags: android, string, variables, int

I'm developing a little* android app and have 9 buttons and 9 images, each named button_# and img#.png
My question is simple, is their a way that I can take an int whose value is between 1 and 9 and reference those objects without having 9 different ifs or a switch. I mean something like being able to do this

```
 myint=4;
 button.setImageResource(R.drawable.img.myint);
```

to set button's image to img4. Of course this doesn't work; I'm looking for some way of concatenating myint onto 'img' (so a string, I guess) and having that be usable to follow R.drawable.

*Just a Univ project, not terribly important but just using a bunch of switches doesn't look good, and moreover I personally doesn't like it.

Edit: Alternately, is there a way to make the images (referencable as in) an array? That's the effect I'm trying to get here anyway because I don't know of a way to use an array here, which would be easier if possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to get the id of drawable in this way:

```
int drawableId = getResources().getIdentifier("resourceName", "drawable", getPackageName());
```